# Ссылка на определённую страницу

Tags: php, wordpress

Допустим в админке, в разделе "Страницы" создана страница со специфическим контентом. И именно на этой странице нужно подключить определённый js-скрипт.
 А также создан виджет "HTML-код", в котором нужно сделать ссылку на эту страницу.
Подскажите, как правильно подключить js-скрипт только на одной странице, а также, как получить ссылку на эту страницу в виджете?
Будет ли правильным решение, если в шаблоне page.php проверять текущую страницу, и в зависимости от $page->ID, подключать скрипт?
А также будет ли правильным просто скопировать ссылку на текущую страницу в виджете?

Comment: Можно и так. Со ссылкой вообще проблем нет, а вот js я бы подключал как положено, в function.php через хук wp_enqueue_scripts с проверкой $page->ID

Comment: @KAGG Design, благодарю. А подскажите, как в functions.php в хуке wp_enqueue_scripts получить значение текущей страницы? что-то типа $page->ID

Comment: Добавьте строчку `$global $post;` и используйте `$post->ID`